# Cassandra server-side timeout configuration for "drop table" command

Tags: cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Is there a timeout setting in the cassandra.yaml file used to cause server-side timeouts when issuing a drop table command?

I'm using the following versions of software:
Cassandra database version: 3.11.2
Cassandra datastax java driver version: 3.4.0

I tried changing cassandra.yaml settings for `write_request_timeout_in_ms`, `truncate_request_timeout_in_ms`, and `request_timeout_in_ms` all to 10 ms and then issued a drop table statement via the datastax java driver.  From my application logs I can see the statement takes about 2 seconds when measured from the client (client and database are all just on my local development machine and doing nothing else but this test) and finishes without a timeout.

I then executed the exact same test but replaced the "drop table" text in the statement with "truncate table" with no other changes and saw the expected timeout `"com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TruncateException: Error during truncate: Truncate timed out - received only 0 responses"`.

I tried searching the Cassandra github project but couldn't find a reference in the code to see how the server side timeouts are applied so I am hoping someone knows the answer to this question.